# Save A List of Documents in MongoDB through Morphia excluding Duplicates

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am trying to save a list of documents in mongodb through morphia.

Entity:

```
class test {
  @Id
  private ObjectId  id;
  private String email_id;
}
```

The Entity has a unique index on a email_id field. 
I am saving the list of test entity using;

```
datastore.save(list_of_test_entity);
```

what i want is if the list contains a Test entity that is a duplicate, dont insert that but continue adding rest.

is it possible with `save()` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `insert` variants with `continueOnError` flag set to false which signals server to do `unordered` write operations on `AdvancedDatastore`.

`AdvancedDatastore` uses `BulkWrites`. This will continue with processing all writes and will throw the last in the order it processed as `DuplicateKeyException`. So you can add `try catch` to ignore the error.

```
AdvancedDatastore datastore = (AdvancedDatastore) morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, dbName);
InsertOptions insertOptions = new InsertOptions();
insertOptions.continueOnError(true);
try {
datastore.insert(list_of_test_entity, insertOptions);
catch (DuplicateKeyException e){
  //Ignore
}
```